# Adding vertical alphabets selector in UIView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, alphabet

Hi
Can I add the vertical alphabets selector thing like that we use in UITableView, in UIView?
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

If you create the UIView yourself you can do whatever you want.

It's not even that hard in your case. Some UILabels as subviews and some logic in `touchesDidSomething:withEvent:` to figure out which label is near the touch.

And a delegate method that tells which section was touched.

---

I think I could need something like that, so I decided to try it.

```
//myIndexSelectorView.m

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame andLabels:(NSArray *)l {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
        self.layer.cornerRadius = frame.size.width/2;
        labels = [l retain];
        NSInteger count;
        for (NSString *string in labels) {
            CGFloat margin = 5.0f;
            CGFloat yPosition = count*(frame.size.height/[labels count]);
            UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(margin, yPosition, frame.size.width-2*margin, frame.size.height/[labels count])] autorelease];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
            label.textColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
            label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            label.text = string;
            [self addSubview:label];
            count++;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)touch:(UITouch *)touch {
    CGPoint touchPosition = [touch locationInView:self];
    NSInteger index = touchPosition.y / (self.bounds.size.height / [labels count]);
    NSLog(@"Touched: %@", [labels objectAtIndex:index]);
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self touch:touch];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    [self touch:touch];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [labels release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

works as expected and looks similar to the index selector of uitableview

[image]

as usual, I didn't check for bugs, and this should not be a copy&paste solution.

Comment: So you say that I will be using different UILabels for all alphabets and will attach some touch event to every UILabel? When user will touch any UILabel, i will execute the background logic attached to that UILabel? Did I get it right?

Comment: I would put the touchLogic inside the view. So you can track taps and moves. like the thing in the tableview does

Answer (score 1):

You can use different UILabels, and set tags to them. Now to detect touches on appropriate label, you can use UITapGestureRecognizer classes

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about keypad, then that cannot be positioned other than the default position with a reason that apple does not allow to change its position.Hope that help you.Thanks.

Comment: I think he means the alphabetical bar you can see in image in the middle here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/Art/types_of_table_views.jpg not the keypad.

Comment: No i am not talking about the keypad, I want that vertical alphabetical list on the right side of my UIView that we use in UITableview

Comment: Yeah, the uh…section…thinger.

Comment: oh sorry i misinterpreted that..!!